# Cleanest handling for malformed app.config

Tags: c#, exception

I have an `app.config` (generated by Visual Studio from the `Settings.settings` file), primarily to contain settings for things such as connection strings.

I access these via `Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName`, and it all works just fine.  When I deploy to a target machine, I have the user edit the .config file to change (for example) the connection string, or one of the other settings; this also works fine... until the user mis-edits the file and accidentally deletes part of a closing XML tag, or some other equally catastrophic XML faux-pas.

At that point, running the app throws a `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException` as soon as one of the settings is read (which makes sense).

My question is, what's the cleanest way to trap for this?  I'd rather not wrap every call to `Properties.Settings` in a try/catch, and making an arbitrary (trapped) check on one of the settings seems, well, arbitrary.

Is there a better way to check that the settings can be read correctly?

Comment: Your problem is not to cleanly handle bad config file but that you're counting on the user to edit it - make some UI for that

Comment: Creating a GUI is something I'd considered, but for something that is essentially a one-off operation done by someone _reasonally_ technical I would rather find a clean way of verifying the settings file first, before going the extra step of writing a tool for it.

Comment: This should be treated the same way as the user accidentally deleting a DLL.  Just make sure that you display a crash message, be sure to write an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException, and that re-installing the app restores a known-good copy of the .config file.

Comment: You can't cleanly trap for all cases of an invalid config file.  The framework read the config file to get information about how to run your assembly--if it can't read the config properly it can't execute your assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant: So if I understand you correctly, I write what's effectively a global event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException, and display a crash message from there?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Are you sure? So far, it runs fine all the way until I try to read one of the settings.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Geoff  Yes, see `supportedRuntime` element.  Clearly it can't run any of your code until it knows what values are on this element.

Comment: @Geoff You'd have to have a try/catch around every piece of code that could possibly read the config file in cases where your code is running--including and BCL code that access the config.  Sometimes not all BCL code is documented as reading the config file.  Plus, you'd have to know what you can do in light of *that* particular config file failure.  The question is like asking "how to handle all possible exceptions cleanly".  i.e. it's not possible.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: My (VS-generated) app.config doesn't include the supportedRuntime element; are we talking about the same thing?  Regardless, I take your point about try/catch, and was hoping there was a clean way to test for a non-corrupt .config before starting, to at least help point the user in the right direction for a fix.

Comment: @Geoff just an example of an element that does get processed before your code is executed.